# Kafka Brokers don't balance partitions after a broker goes down

Tags: apache-kafka

We have a 3-broker 3-zookeeper cluster and we've taken down a broker. We have total of 180 partitions, each of the topics have 2 replicas. When a node is taken down, there are 75 under replicated partitions and it stays that way and it doesn't look like anything happens. When I start up the broker I took down, the partitions are quickly picked up by it and it works ok.

The machines are quite big (30gb ram, fast disks) and all the data is 10gb on each broker so I have no idea why it wouldn't move the partitions quickly from a node that is down to a node that is still up, seems like it's not aware that the node was taken down.

Any tips? How can I monitor the recovery process after a node is taken down?

Kafka version - 2.6.0

Answer (score 1):

This is by design, no data is moved off the broker until you manually move partitions off of it first using `kafka-reassign-partitions`

Similarly, you'd need to do this if you're trying to fully remove a node from the cluster, which is effectively the same behavior of having it crash and never come back

Comment: I'm not trying to remove it for good, just simulating a situation when a node goes down for whatever reason. On my other clusters (2.0.0/2.3.1) when 1 node goes down the other rebalance as expected, but here it looks like no attempt is being made even though in the logs it recognizes that a broker was stopped. When I try to run kafka-consumer-groups.sh to see the current lag I get "org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for a node assignment." even though there are 2 nodes still in the cluster.

Comment: When I bring the 3rd broker back up everything works again, but at this current state 1 failed broker causes the entire cluster to fail.

Comment: From the question, sounded like you're expecting data to be moved off a broker that's no longer available. That's what rebalancing means in terms of the brokers, and this doesn't happen. A new controller is elected and available in-sync partitions become leaders. Any consumer group rebalances should happen automatically, but if you lose the Kafka Controller node and your min ISR shrink into a bad state, then sure, you should expect some of these errors unless you allow for unclean leader election

Comment: After clearing data on zookeeper rolling restart the cluster, the cluster now keeps ingesting data and 1 broker down does not cause to whole cluster to fail and doesn't cause lag but it's still stuck on those 75 under replicated partitions. Do you know why it would not distribute them between the available brokers? It seems to only drop when we bring back the broker we took down. Most of our configs are the default...

Comment: As answered, the broker is unavailable. No data can be moved away from it since Zookeeper still thinks it has partitions that need to be kept in sync with the rest of the cluster.

Comment: It seems like you do not understand what my problem is, it is quite simple. Out of 3 brokers, 1 goes down. A topic has replication factor of 2, so the 2 brokers that are still up need to allocate the under replicated partitions but they don't do anything. In my other clusters, when this happens, the rest of the brokers DO allocate the under replicated partitions to themselves.

Comment: I understand the question fine. What I don't know is if the broker that went down is the Controller or if you've enabled unclean leader election... And if you have a replication factor of only 2 and the min ISR is also 2, then having one of the brokers down (one of the replicas) causes the cluster to think that the topic is under replicated. There's no data on the other third healthy broker that can make up for that... and then you'll get errors in the clients, specifically if you have producer acks at 1 or all